# Non parallel plan with row level security predicate to check server role

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019, parallelism, row-level-security

While exploring Row Level Security I picked up that whenever I had it enabled it was not creating any parallel query plans.

In SQL Server 2019 this gave me
`NonParallelPlanReason="CouldNotGenerateValidParallelPlan"`

In SQL Server 2022 this gave me the more detailed `“NonParallelPlanReason="NonParallelizableIntrinsicFunction"`

Where my security predicate looks like -

```
CREATE FUNCTION Security.fn_SecurityPredicateTenantId(@TenantId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_securityPredicateResult
WHERE
    (
        IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('RLS_Filtered_AppRole') = 1
        AND CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'TenantId') AS uniqueidentifier) = @TenantId
    )
    OR
    (
        IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('RLS_FullAccess_AppRole') = 1
        OR IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('RLS_FullAccess_StaffUserRole') = 1     
    );
GO
```

The session context is fine, I don't have 11042 or 9432 flags enabled (as per the reply here [Non parallel plan only in Azure when SESSION_CONTEXT is used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308059/non-parallel-plan-only-in-azure-when-session-context-is-used))

This narrowed it down to the IS_SRVROLEMEMBER calls, sure enough running
`select 1 as 'Hi' where IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('RLS_Filtered_AppRole') = 1` gives me the same intrinsic function error.

Thinking I'd have to tact to use database roles or principals I tried these, which both face the same error

```
select 1 as 'Hi' where IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('RLS_Filtered_AppRole') = 1
select 1 as 'Hi' where IS_MEMBER('RLS_Filtered_AppRole') = 1
select 1 as 'Hi' where DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID() = 1
```

Query plan of all 3 with NonParallelizableIntrinsicFunction - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJPIYpVZT

Is there a better way how I should be checking the server/database roles of my users within my row level security predicate function?

This has been [reported to Microsoft Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/3d8f808b-9d6b-ee11-a81c-002248544521) as well.